# Неверное поле "" в классе

Tags: java, парсер, list, map

Вот класс:

```java
import at.favre.lib.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt;
import com.jsoniter.JsonIterator;
import com.jsoniter.any.Any;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.Map.entry;

public class Helper {
    public static class ConnectionPath {
        String[] pathParts;
        Map<String, String> params;

        public ConnectionPath (String[] pathParts, Map<String, String> params) {
            this.pathParts = pathParts;
            this.params = params;
        }
    }

    public static class MessagePacket {
        final String hash;
        final String[] intention;
        final String preData;
        Object postData;

        public MessagePacket (String[] intention, String controlSum, String data) {
            this.intention = intention;
            this.hash = controlSum;
            this.preData = data;
        }

        public void parseData (Class pattern) {
            postData = JsonIterator.deserialize(preData, pattern);
        }
    }

    @Contract("_ -> new")
    public static @NotNull ConnectionPath parseURI (@NotNull String uri) {
        int index = uri.indexOf('?');
        String path = uri.substring(0, index);
        String query = uri.substring(index + 1);

        String[] pathParts = path.split("/");

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        for (String param : query.split("&")) {
            String[] entry = param.split("=");

            params.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
        }

        return new ConnectionPath(pathParts, params);
    }

    @Contract("_ -> new")
    public static @NotNull MessagePacket parsePacket (@NotNull String packet) {
        String[] splitPacket = packet.split("%");

        return new MessagePacket(splitPacket[0].split("-"), splitPacket[1], splitPacket[2]);
    }

    public static Boolean verifierBCrypt (@NotNull String data, byte[] hash_data) {
        return BCrypt.verifyer().verify(Arrays.copyOfRange(data.toCharArray(), 0, Math.min(data.toCharArray().length, 72)), hash_data).verified;
    }

    public static String SHA512 (String string) {
        MessageDigest md;

        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException _) {
            return string;
        }

        byte[] bytes = md.digest(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (byte aByte : bytes) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((aByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Я тестирую:

```java
public class Starter {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Helper.parseURI("/id=4&token=user.4.wsm3mOlDwbhaHD0iG33nQ9CwBEIf3B7al5Bylki1XpuKOHAxy2og1mmqdIs5yALmW");

        System.out.println("Прошло!");
    }
}
```

Но программа вылетает:

```
C:\Users\Fluorum\.jdks\sapmachine-21\bin\java.exe --enable-preview "-javaagent:C:\Users\Fluorum\AppData\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition\lib\idea_rt.jar=56493:C:\Users\Fluorum\AppData\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath E:\Projects\GigaChat\RTCD\out\production\RTCD;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\com\jsoniter\jsoniter\0.9.23\jsoniter-0.9.23.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\java-websocket\Java-WebSocket\1.5.4\Java-WebSocket-1.5.4.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.6\slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\at\favre\lib\bcrypt\0.10.2\bcrypt-0.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\at\favre\lib\bytes\1.5.0\bytes-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\24.0.0\annotations-24.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.6.0\postgresql-42.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.31.0\checker-qual-3.31.0.jar Starter
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal field name "" in class Helper
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at Starter.main(Starter.java:7)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Откуда код берёт пустое поле? Единственное предположение - ключи хэш-мапы. Но в данной строке они же не пустые?

**UPD** Попробовал сделать выноску:

```java
public class Starter {
    @Contract("_ -> new")
    public static @NotNull Helper.ConnectionPath parseURI (@NotNull String uri) {
        int index = uri.indexOf('?');
        String path = uri.substring(0, index);
        String query = uri.substring(index + 1);

        String[] pathParts = path.split("/");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pathParts));

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        for (String param : query.split("&")) {
            String[] entry = param.split("=");
            System.out.println("-----");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(entry));
            params.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
        }

        return new Helper.ConnectionPath(pathParts, params);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Helper.ConnectionPath returner = parseURI("/id=4&token=user.4.wsm3mOlDwbhaHD0iG33nQ9CwBEIf3B7al5Bylki1XpuKOHAxy2og1mmqdIs5yALmW");

        System.out.println("Прошло!");
        System.out.println(returner);
    }
}
```

Но теперь ошибка вообще другая:

```
C:\Users\Fluorum\.jdks\sapmachine-21\bin\java.exe --enable-preview "-javaagent:C:\Users\Fluorum\AppData\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition\lib\idea_rt.jar=60335:C:\Users\Fluorum\AppData\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath E:\Projects\GigaChat\RTCD\out\production\RTCD;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\com\jsoniter\jsoniter\0.9.23\jsoniter-0.9.23.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\java-websocket\Java-WebSocket\1.5.4\Java-WebSocket-1.5.4.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.6\slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\at\favre\lib\bcrypt\0.10.2\bcrypt-0.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\at\favre\lib\bytes\1.5.0\bytes-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\24.0.0\annotations-24.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.6.0\postgresql-42.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Fluorum\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.31.0\checker-qual-3.31.0.jar Starter
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [0, -1) out of bounds for length 84
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:349)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4861)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2830)
    at Starter.parseURI(Starter.java:12)
    at Starter.main(Starter.java:35)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**UDP 2** Ещё поэксперементировал.
Обнаружил, что если закомментировать метод `SHA512` (функцию хэширования по `SHA-512`), то ошибка исчезает и всё работает.

Comment: Что за JDK и версия?

Comment: sapmachine-21 BETA+. Ну в которой включены все бета-функции 21-ой.

Comment: Написано же - https://clck.ru/35xavs

Comment: В `sapmachine-21+24` только добавили `JEP 443: Unnamed Patterns and Variable`, обновите если надо. Точную версию JDK вы так и не указали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После экспериментов, я выяснил проблему. Она оказалась вообще не связанной с парсером. Почему-то, несмотря на 21-ую Java он не пропускал вот такой код (хотя IDEA не ругается):

```java
public static String SHA512 (String string) {
    MessageDigest md;

    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException _) {
        return string;
    }

    byte[] bytes = md.digest(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (byte aByte : bytes) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((aByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Хотя вот такой спокойно:

```java
public static String SHA512 (String string) {
    MessageDigest md;

    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return string;
    }

    byte[] bytes = md.digest(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (byte aByte : bytes) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((aByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `JEP 443: Unnamed Patterns and Variable` идет как `preview` в JDK 21, возможно в вашей BETA+ его и нет.

Comment: Что значит "не пропускал код"?  Разница между двумя фрагментами кода в том, что в первом используется одиночное подчеркивание в названии переменной `catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException _)`, но, начиная с Java 9 (!), [`_` является ключевым словом](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/language/toc.htm#JSLAN-GUID-E409CC44-9A8F-4043-82C8-6B95CD939296): _If you use the underscore character (`"_"`) an identifier, your source code can no longer be compiled._

Comment: @NowhereMan, так в 21-ой Java разрешили так делать?

Comment: Да, но как `preview-feature`, о чём было указано выше.  А как у вас был _скомпилирован_ код с фичей JEP 443?  Должны были задаваться опции для компилятора `javac --release 21 --enable-preview`.

Comment: @NowhereMan, я вроде ставил именно `preview-feature` галочку. Но тогда бы и IDEA ругалась бы.